# What method KeyAgreement.generateSecret(String algorithm) does?

Tags: java, security, encryption

We implemented Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange algorithm:

```
KeyAgreement aKeyAgree = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");

keyAgreement.init(myPrivateKey);
keyAgreement.doPhase(otherPublicKey)
```

Now we need to generate a secret to use for AES encryption. There is method `generateSecret(String algorithm)`. I think I should call it with `'AES'` argument.

But for DH I use 512-bit length public keys so the secret should be 512-bit length too. But AES allows 256-bit length keys as the maximum. The plain method `generateSecret()` without parameters returns 512-bit DH secret. But what `generateSecret(String)` does? How it transforms 512-bit secret to 256/128-bit AES key?

Comment: DH needs keys that are about as long as RSA keys. Hence use keys that are at least 1024 bits long. From the generated DH secret generate an AES key by using a hash function, for example SHA-256.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method just truncate generatedSecret().

Answer (score 4):

Diffie-Hellman is a key agreement protocol; AES is a symmetric encryption algorithm.

The no-argument `generateSecret()` call provides a key of the default size for the key agreement algorithm.  Passing the algorithm name to `generateSecret` will give you a key with the appropriate size for your algorithm (i.e. shortened to 256 bits for AES).

I found a page that shows an example.

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.crypto/KeyAgree.html

I would expect you can just replace "DES" in the example with "AES" or whatever symmetric key algorithm you'd like to use.

Comment: I first generate the shared secret with Diffie-Hellman algo then use the generated key to encrypt data with AES.

Comment: I don't try to replace one with another. I just try to use them both in conjunction.