# How to get AES secret key from DH secret key

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes, diffie-hellman

I have the following code that converts a DH secret key to AES secret key. This used to work until [Oracle JRE 8u161](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8u161-relnotes-4021379.html) when they started restricting creation of DH keys < 1024 in `java.security` file. Now, I will get `NoSuchAlgorithmException: Unsupported secret key algorithm AES` at the last line.

```java
PrivateKey privKey = null;
PublicKey pubKey = null;
PublicKey agreement = null;

KeyAgreement keyAgreement = KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH");
keyAgreement.init(privKey);
keyAgreement.doPhase(pubKey, false);
keyAgreement.doPhase(agreement, true);
SecretKey key = keyAgreement.generateSecret("AES");
```

I tried changing the last line to this. I can encrypt and decrypt using the new keys but this does not work with the old keys generated before.

```java
byte[] encodedKey = keyAgreement.generateSecret();
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(encodedKey, 0, encodedKey.length, "AES");
```

I found a similar SO question [What metod KeyAgreement.generateSecret(String algorithm) does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3503006/what-metod-keyagreement-generatesecretstring-algorithm-does) but I am still clueless on how I can fix this without breaking the existing keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally key size requirements are checked in the `Cipher` and `KeyAgreement` class itself rather than the service implementation by the provider. It is of course try to test another provider such as the Bouncy Castle provider regardless [**EDIT**: this seems to work in this case, so the key size restraints are in the default provider delivered with the Java runtime, using the "BC" provider seems to work fine, [see the comment below the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413693/how-to-get-aes-secret-key-from-dh-secret-key/48476790#comment83958988_48476790)].

If using another provider doesn't work then use the Bouncy Castle lightweight API (`org.bouncycastle.**` classes) to use another software implementation of DH, bypassing the `KeyAgreement` class altogether. Stepping outside the JCA / `KeyAgreement` should however be avoided.

Needless to say, the requirements of not using < 1024 bits keys are there for a reason, they are not considered secure anymore. Upgrade your security ASAP!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We have added BC as a provider but we were not explicitly using it. Initializing the `KeyAgreement` as `KeyAgreement.getInstance("DH", "BC")` does indeed solve our issue for now.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with Oracle/Sun-providers is not the DH keysize limitation in java.security, which only applies to TLS/SSL (i.e. JSSE), but this item slightly further down in the release notes you linked:

> - Stricter key generation
>
> The `generateSecret(String)` method has been mostly disabled in the `javax.crypto.KeyAgreement` services of the SunJCE and SunPKCS11 providers. Invoking this method for these providers will result in a `NoSuchAlgorithmException` for most algorithm string arguments. The previous behavior of this method can be re-enabled by setting the value of the `jdk.crypto.KeyAgreement.legacyKDF` system property to `true` (case insensitive). Re-enabling this method by setting this system property is not recommended.

The next paragraphs basically say, not very clearly, that using DH correctly requires a suitable KDF, but this operation doesn't provide/define the KDF, so it can't ensure suitability, and instead you should use the no-argument `generateSecretKey()` method to get the raw DH value and apply a suitable KDF yourself; they give SP800-56Ar2 and plain hash as examples.

BouncyCastle went the other way; in 1.60 it has several `KeyAgreement` algorithms with the KDF encoded like `DHwithSHA256CKDF`.